# How to Prevent jQuery from Converting &#160; Back to &nbsp; when setting innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

Run the following in your console:

`$('<div>&#160;</div>')`

And you'll get

`[<div>&nbsp;</div>]`

I need jQuery to leave the unicode intact (I'm sending HTML off as XML and it needs to be valid).

How do I fix this?

Comment: jQuery is not doing that; it's the browser. Why are you wrapping it with jQuery in the first place?

Comment: I'm doing some pre-processing code before I send it off to the server. The example above is simplified to highlight the issue.

Comment: The jQuery code builds HTML fragments by leveraging DOM APIs. When you get the contents back, you're getting it the way the browser feels like giving it to you. `&nbsp;` is valid HTML and that's pretty much what browsers think you're interested in.

Comment: Use a specialized library like [___he___](http://mths.be/he) for HTML entity encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna use the value `&#160;` later you can do the following workaround, may not be the best, but it gives the desired result: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tpo5dsu5/)**

```
$('body').append('<div>&#-160;</div>');
var value=$('div').html().split('-');
value[0]=value[0].replace(/amp;/,'');
alert(value[0]+value[1]);
```

the idea is to put a `-` in the middle of the value, then remove it and separate the value from that part, and then join them together to make it as it was before!

as I said before, it is just a workaround!